# SQL - get most recent insert with autoincrementing id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
  id                INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ssn               LONG        NOT NULL,
  ethnicity         VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ssn)
);
```

With indexes on ethnicity for when i want a list of all people of a certain background.

If I want to make a Select statement of the last person of a certain ethnicity that was inserted into the DB based on the auto incrementing ID (the latest person would be the highest number) would this be the most effective way of doing it?:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE ethnicity = "caucasian";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select the record and order by your field name `DESC`.

```
SELECT id 
FROM TableName 
WHERE ethnicity = 'caucasian' 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```